# How to get a gulp stream from a vinyl object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, gulp

How can I create a stream using a [vinyl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl) object so I can use gulp.js plugins on it?

Example with a vinyl object:

```
var file = getFoo();  // An in-memory file as a vinyl object.
return gulp.src(file) // What to do here? gulp.src only accepts globs.
    .pipe(css(opts))      // (gulp-clean-css)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('...'));
```

lofihelsinki's comment (`return file.pipe(css())...`) solves this first case.

Example with a vinyl object and a stream:

```
var file = getFoo();
return merge(gulp.src('*.css'), file)
    .pipe(concat('foobar.css'))
    .pipe(css(opts))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('...'));
```

Example with two vinyl objects:

```
var file1 = getFoo();
var file2 = getBar();
return merge(file1, file2)      // (gulp-merge)
    .pipe(concat('foobar.css')) // (gulp-concat)
    .pipe(css(opts))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('...'));
```

Comment: Does `return file.pipe(css())` work?

Comment: It works, thank you! I have one other case that it does not help though, I'll update the question in a min.

Comment: I'll turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vinyl-source-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-source-stream) or equivalent (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-streamify)
and add new `pipe` to convert to the stream.
You can explicitly do that with [gulp-map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-map) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66312042/1744914)

Answer (score -1):

File itself is a usable object

```
var file = getFoo();
return file
    .pipe(css(opts))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('...'));
```

Comment: Thank you. I added two more examples after your comment yesterday. While the question remains the same (creating a stream using a vinyl object), calling the File's pipe does not cover the cases where there is a function accepting streams.

Comment: If only an empty pipe (`file.pipe()`) was a viable way to convert the file to a stream. Maybe writing a dumb gulp function to pass the file contents as-is like `file.pipe(asIs())` would help, I'll take a look at this.

Comment: No, TypeError: file.pipe is not a function.

Answer (score -1):

For two streams, use [`gulp-buffer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-buffer)

```
var buffer = require('gulp-buffer');

var file1 = getFoo();
var file2 = getBar();

return merge(file1, file2)      // (gulp-merge)
    .pipe(buffer())             // (gulp-buffer)
    .pipe(concat('foobar.css')) // (gulp-concat)
    .pipe(css(opts))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('...'));
```