# gulp add pipe to convert to Vinyl objects

Tags: gulp, internationalization, i18next, gulp-dest

I have upgraded to gulp `4.0.2` version I need to update one of the tasks

```
const debug = require('gulp-debug');
const i18nextParser = require('i18next-parser');

function myTask() {
  return gulp
    .src(['./js/**/*.js', './js/**/*.jsx'])
    .pipe(
      i18nextParser({
        locales: ['en', 'de'],
        functions: ['translate'],
        output: '/opt/locales/'
      })
    )
    .pipe(debug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/opt/locales/'));
});
```

I want these files to be converted to Vinyl objects:

```
[17:04:32] gulp-debug: opt/locales/de/translation.json
[17:04:32] gulp-debug: opt/locales/de/translation_old.json
[17:04:32] gulp-debug: opt/locales/en/translation.json
[17:04:32] gulp-debug: opt/locales/en/translation_old.json
```

otherwise I have and error

```
Error: Received a non-Vinyl object in `dest()`
```

Is there a function that I can pipe to in order to make this task work properly?

`i18next-parser` version is `0.7.0`. Upgrading to latest `3.6.0` version doesn't produce any output at all.

Comment: There is similar question without a proper solution though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138005/how-to-get-a-gulp-stream-from-a-vinyl-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this by adding extra step using [gulp-map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-map)

```
const map = require('gulp-map');
const Vinyl = require('vinyl');

  return gulp
    .src(['./js/*.js', './js/*.jsx'])
    .pipe(
      i18nextParser({
        locales: ['en', 'de'],
        functions: ['translate'],

        output: JSON_DIR
      })
    )
    .pipe(map(function(file) {
      // Explicitly convert to Vinyl object otherwise `gulp.dest()` will fail
      return new Vinyl(file);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(JSON_DIR));
```

Comment: Man you saved me! It really works! After updating to version 4 of gulp, I could not fix this error and your solution helped!